# Using Yoneda lemma, the pair $(U, s)$ representing presheaf $F$ are unique up to unique isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

I'm quoting from the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/001L):

> **Definition 4.3.6.** A contravariant functor $C \to \text{Sets}$ is said to be representable if it is isomorphic to the functor of points $h_u$ for some object $u$ of $C$.
>
> Let $C$ be a category and let $F: C^{op} \to \text{Sets}$ be a representable functor.  Choose an object $u$ of $C$ and an isomorphism $s : h_u \to F$.  The Yoneda lemma guarantees that **the pair $(u,s)$ is unique up to unique isomorphism.** The object $u$ is called an object representing $F$.

I am having trouble with the bolded part.  I understand how to prove the Yoneda lemma as seen here in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94007/proof-of-yoneda-lemma/2301439#2301439).

So how do we go from $\text{Nat}(h_u, F) \simeq F(u)$ to *$(u,s)$ is unique up to unique isomorphism?*  Please guide me as someone new to Yoneda lemma application.

### Attempt

We have that $s : F \simeq h_u$ is a natural isomorphism of functors. Now $u$ is uniquely determined from $h_u$ and thus $s$ clearly.  If $s' : F \simeq h_v$ then $s' \circ \theta = s$ for some natural isomorphism $\theta$ I suppose.  And also $u \simeq v$.  I guess I need to prove that now.

Well do $\theta = s'^{-1} s$  then clearly that isomorphism is unique.  We can do that since they compose: $h_u \simeq F \simeq h_v$.   Now $u \simeq v$ anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a diagram

$$ \begin{matrix} h_u &\xrightarrow{s}& F 
\\ & & \ \ \ \uparrow \small s'
\\ & & h_{u'} \end{matrix} $$

Then the only way to complete this diagram with a map $h_u \to h_{u'}$ to get a commutative triangle is with $(s')^{-1} s$.

The Yoneda lemma implies that there is exactly one morphism $u \to u'$ for which the induced map $h_u \to h_{u'}$ is $(s')^{-1} s$

Comment: Oh I see, $u \to u'$ induces the map $h_u \to h_{u'}$ .  I did learn that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key is applying Yoneda lemma with $F=h_v$, which will yield ${\rm Nat}(h_u,h_v)\cong \hom(u,v)$.

Let $(v,t)$ be another such pair, i.e. $v\in Ob\,C$ and $t:h_v\to F$ natural isomorphism.

Now we have $t^{-1}\circ s:h_u\to h_v$, thus it has a unique correspondent $\gamma:u\to v$ which has an inverse, namely the correspondent of $s^{-1}\circ t:h_v\to h_u$. 
(To prove they're indeed inverses, naturality conditions have to be used.)